Adjacent roots in root systems
In Fulton and Harris : while dealing with rank $2 $ root systems, authors say that the angle between two roots must be
the same for any pair of adjacent roots in a two-dimensional root system. In two dimensional the notion of adjacent roots is pretty geometric and intuitive. I was wondering given roots $\alpha$ and $ \beta$ how to tell that they are adjacent or not?
In two dimensional we can think adjacent roots as this : consider the unbounded triangular region between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and we can say that these two roots are adjacent if there are no roots in this region.
Is there a precise definition of adjacent roots in higher dimensions?

That being said, for any two roots, you can restrict to the subspace spanned by those two roots, and the roots contained therein, so you'll be back to two dimensions (or less).

@TorstenSchoeneberg Fixed the typos

As I say in a comment: Given two linearly independent roots $\alpha, \beta$, you can always restrict to the subspace spanned by them, and look at the roots contained therein; they will form a rank $2$ root system, so you can use the definition of "adjacent" there.
However, the statement you quote will no longer be true -- there are rather obvious reducible counterexamples, but it holds not even in irreducible root systems, as one look at e.g. a root system of type $A_3$ shows: With this definition, there are now pairs of adjacent roots of angle $\pi/3$ as well as with angle $\pi/2$.
For some other purposes, the idea to restrict to subsystems spanned by e.g. a pair of roots works nicely. --- I am not aware of a differing definition of "adjacent" that would give the result, unless you basically force it in the definition (as in: call two roots adjacent if the angle between them is the minimal angle between any two roots).
